# What happens to previous data on new assignment?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, vector, types

Consider the following code -

```
{
    int n = 3;
    n = 5;

    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3 .... 3242};
    v = std::vector<int>{10000, 10001, 10002... 50000};
}
```

for primitive data types like `int`, it can simply overwrite the previous memory location with the new value and get away with it. However what happens to types like `std::vector`, where length of previous values might not be same as the new assignment.

In other words, what happens to the part `{ 1, 2, 3 .... 3000}` when v is reassigned to new `{10000, 10001, 10002... 50000}` value. Does it simply throw away the previous value and reassign the internal pointers to new locations? Or does it overwrites the previous locations with new data as much as it can, and either reallocates new memory in case of large assignment or clears out existing memory in case of shorter assignment thus preserving the `capacity()` of initial vector?

Would this be preferable *anywhere* over clearing out the contents (`v=vector<int>{}`vs`.clear()`) instead because I saw this type of code somewhere?

Comment: It could do either of those, the decision is up to the implementor of `vector`

Comment: You are using a move assignment. The standard essentially requires that the existing data be discarded and all its elements destroyed, and the new data moved over from the right hand side. This is because the operation must be linear in the current size of the recipient vector, and independent of the size of the donor. Also, all references, pointers and iterators to elements of the donor must remain valid (but now refer to the elements in the destination) - this, too, precludes anything like "copy elements from right to left".

Comment: Many things happens on this 4th line, but you are likely interested in a call to [`vector::operator=()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D). You can step into this function with a debugger to see what exactly happens on your implementation of `std::vector`. Do it in debug build, because release build will likely optimize everything away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However what happens to types like std::vector, where sizes of previous value might not be same as the new assignment.

I take it you mean that the length of the new data array might be different?

`std::vector` separates the concerns of its internal storage and how much of that storage is in use. If the new data has fewer, the same, or a few more elements, objects typically re-use the same storage. It's more complex than simply being overwritten because old objects will need their destructors called (if they are not PODS), but essentially, yes. They are overwritten (safely).

If you look at the source code of `std::vector` you'll see a lot of quite complex code covering all the cases you mention, plus some more you have not.

Writing an exception-safe, optimally-efficient vector is not trivial.

Unless you are interested in the implementation (because you want to improve it, maintain it, or are just curious) the documentation of `std::vector`'s behaviour is sufficient to reason about expectations you may have of it.

Pay particular attention to which operations cause the iterators to be invalidated. This is a useful hint that internal objects are either being moved within storage, or new storage may be allocated.

link: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: While your answer is correct in general ("don't worry about it"), the *specific* example the OP gave is of a move assignment.  The guarantees that the move assignment gives about complexity (if the allocators compare equal, the complexity is independent of the size of the rhs), means that move assignment *must* be "throw away old storage, adopt storage from rhs".

Comment: @MartinBonner agree - the answer is simplistic. I felt a short answer with a link to docs might be better, as to write a full explanation of std::vector, covering all cases is shockingly complicated for such a simple structure!